# VLOOKUP value not available to formula or function but it should be

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I am using the following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(E9, 'Raw data'!$A$1:$I$45857, 9, FALSE)
```

I have two tabs and I want one column in my first sheet to lookup the # value found in 'raw data' associated with the ID number found in column E (data begins on cell E9). my second tab, 'raw data', includes that same field as found starting on E9 in sheet 1 within the data range A1:I45857. The column I want returned from 'raw data' is the 9th column. I want to be exact matches only.

What I think excel is thinking - look for e9 in the array 'raw data' and when I see it, return the value that I find in the 9th column of that row within array 'raw data'.

What excel is saying - A value is not available to the formula or function

I am confused because the value is in fact available within that array. when I filter and search for just one of the IDs, I find it in both sheets. The data type is number for both columns and there are no rogue spaces or anything...

My goal is ultimately to take a subset of ids and look at the difference between the # found on sheet1 and the number found on 'raw data'. I am Vlookup-ing so that i can grab the # value on 'raw data, set it right next to the # i am comparing it to on sheet1 and then I can pivot the data to aggregate both of those numbers based on ID and create a calculated field showing the % difference between the two.

Any input on how to fix my vlookup or a workaround to join my # from 'raw data' to sheet1 based on a common ID is MUCH appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend that you look into the combination of INDEX & MATCH, rather than VLOOKUP, for situations like this. VLOOKUP has 2 main flaws: (1) you have to order your data so that your search term is the left-most column of a continuous data block [as you have just seen]; and (2) it is volatile, meaning that when a column is inserted within your data block, it will no longer properly 'count' the number of columns to move to retrieve your data.

MATCH is like half of VLOOKUP. You give MATCH a specific column or row, and a value to search for, and it will simply return the number of cells in it had to move to find that value.

```
=MATCH(A1,B:B,0)
```

This says 'look at B:B, and tell me what row the value of A1 appears on'.

INDEX is like the other half of VLOOKUP. You give INDEX a group of cells (either a row, column, or a 2D range), and a specific row number (plus potentially a column number), and it will return the value for that cell.

```
=INDEX(C:C,5)
```

This gives you the value of cell C5, which is the 5th row found in the column given to INDEX. Combine these two formulas and it will return the value of column C, where column B matches A1:

```
=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(A1,B:B,0))
```

This formula gives an identical result to

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,B:C,0)
```

VLOOKUP looks simpler here, but INDEX & MATCH is much more versatile - in your case, you wouldn't have needed to reorder your data to get it to work, you could have used the formula:

```
=INDEX('Raw Data'!I:I,MATCH(E9,'Raw Data'!E:E,0))
```

Once you get into the habit of using INDEX / MATCH over vlookup, you will find that your data is a lot more flexible to manage.

Comment: Nice call with Index/Match - it's a great tool to learn. Great explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work by making my ID field in 'raw data' the leftmost column.

Comment: Yep. That's how [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) makes its match. :)

Comment: Nick, see @Grade'Eh'Bacon's reply about Index/Match.  It is like vlookup, but a little more powerful as you don't have to have your data laid out from "left to right" like for vLookup.

Comment: It's also worth checking that you've ordered the lookup column in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to start the Vlookup in column A. If the ID column is not in column A, Vlookup can still work, as long as the ID column is to the left of the column you want to return. So, if you want to return the value from column I, and the ID column is in column F, you can leave the table as it is and change the Vlookup to

```
=VLOOKUP(E9, 'Raw data'!$F$1:$I$45857, 4, FALSE)
```

This will look for the match in column F and returns the value from the fourth column, which is column I.